# PDF: keep the top half of each page (e-ticket "repaging")

Tags: pdf

E-tickets for airplane or train often contain all necessary information on the top half of the page, then extra info and ads in the lower half. For multiple legs or several passengers it annoys me to print 4 or 8 pages when half this would be enough. (Airlines or train companies don't want any resize)

I think that an easy solution to repage the top-halves, 2 on each page, would be useful to many of those who want a paper copy of their e-tickets (and environmentally friendly). I'm working on one for linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under linux with the [`pdfjam`](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) package I could do:

```
pdfjam input.pdf --trim '0cm 17cm 0cm 0cm' --clip true --landscape --nup '1x2' --no-landscape -o output.pdf
```

It should also work with Mac.